# Severe Genshin Impact key delay

Tags: windows-10, genshin-impact, boot-camp, windows-11

Is it just me or are there any other people experiencing this bug where there is a severe key delay that occurs several times every minute in Genshin Impact on Mac Bootcamp?
Never had this input delay happen on any other apps or times when I am not running Genshin Impact for some reason. This kind of made the Glorious Drumalong Festival unplayable...
I also noticed how sometimes, when I am having some severe key lag issues, Windows started opening up a whole bunch of applications which can be referred to this issue: [Windows opening up random applications but after fixing it](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/random-applications-opening-when-pressing-any-key/6ea9433a-6ca3-475f-a854-6949c78d530d) (temporarily - there's no permanent fix that I have found -), there's still severe lag delay...

Any solutions so far?

Solutions that I have attempted so far:

- Reimage bootcamp to Windows 10
- Update drivers (officially)
- Update drivers (unofficially using driver booster (kind of broke the computer last time I tried it))
- Reinstalled drivers
- Reinstalled Genshin Impact

[Delayed input video link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pz8K0-9f-9lw0fiYWi1ms6vF2NxUwgWR/view?usp=sharing) (on Google Drive).

I'm on an Apple Macbook Air 2015 running Windows 11.

Comment: Anyway to try this out on Windows 10?

Comment: Not sure on how to reproduce this issue on other windows devices but you might be able to reproduce this issue with a macbook air bootcamp windows. This same issue arises in windows 10 as well when I tried it. This can happen randomly so reproducing it can be hard I guess...

Comment: As this seem more like Bootcamp you might have more luck asking on https://apple.stackexchange.com/ or https://superuser.com/

Comment: Just got my post deleted on superuser since moderators thought that this problem is a game related problem... I will try to post this on apple stack exchange and hope to find a solution to this issue! Thanks!